# Where the hell is Vincent?

Tags: cipher, strategy, lateral-thinking

Vincent was a software engineer working at Bell Inc, and well...he's gone insane. He is said to suffer from clinical schizophrenia, autism and severe anxiety. But there's one golden fact about his mind, he possesses an IQ above the limits that God himself placed on mankind's marvelous intelligence. In simple terms, Vincent has a 395 IQ.

On a sunny sunday during the summer of 1972, Vincent kidnapped Jeremy Kinderman (the chairman of Bell) very cleverly and sent a kind telegraph to the board of directors of Bell Inc. The telegraph was as follows,

```
Ybaqba is a word. And that's all that matters. 
But another thing that could potentially matter is that the word rots 13 times.
```

Vincent took Jeremy's private jetplane and escorted him to some european city. Very reliable reports suggest that Vincent could have only escorted him to one of the following cities; Prague, London, Malmedy, Warsaw or Berlin.

After 8 days had passed since the kidnapping, Vincent sent yet another telegraph to the board of directors or more specifically, to Bertrand as he was trying to trace the location of his telegraph very stubbornly. The telegraph was as follows,

```
I have only one thing to say to you.
efrgebegusuaoflryoho!
```

The police and many other departments are involved in trying to arrest Vincent and save Jeremy. The telegraphs include cryptic strings, perhaps they could mean something. Right now, all we want is the location of Vincent.

*What do the secret strings tell and where in the world has Vincent escorted Jeremy to?*

Comment: Dear God, minus 1 for the limits that you've placed on mankind's marvelous intelligence.

Comment: I think you could change Malmedy for something else because unlike other cities, it has seven letters instead of six.

Comment: O almighty could you give us a hint?

Comment: Second string isn't ROT anything.

Answer (score 6):

First string:

> After using ROT-conversion of 13 ('Y' becomes 'L', 'b' becomes 'o' and so on):
>  London

Meh, stop with the plussing, I didn't even decode the 2nd string.
I think I need a hint for this one...

Answer (score 3):

Second string is

> an anagram of "Royal George Buff House"

...but I'm not really sure that's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear from the second string that Vincent snapped and is now thinking he is Jabba the Hutt. He stole Jeremy away to

> London

and is now requesting them to bring Han Solo.